# execute user's input in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, user-input

I have a sikuli script that need an app opened to works. I created an executable test_app.sh

```
/home/local/Applications/App/launch_app&
/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0.172/bin/java -jar sikulix.jar -r executable.sikuli
```

So the first line launch the app and the second run my sikuli script on it and I would like to remove the first line and let the user enter his path to the app which I won't know. I'm sure there is an easy way maybe with `read -p` or something but I didn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the output of the read command and execute it e.g.

```
$ cat 1.sh
echo "I am script $0"

$ cat 2.sh
read script
. $script

$ bash 2.sh
1.sh
I am script 1.sh
```

It works for full paths too:

```
$ bash 2.sh
/home/my_user/1.sh
I am script 1.sh
```

Comment: Ok i'm not sure I understood all that but I'm going to try that thank you !

Comment: If you want to run a script you can just call it by prefixing it with .   so you can say read <whatever> and you can call $<whatever> as a substitute. What else are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a parameterized bash script:

script.sh content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP_NAME=$1 # get parameter

"${APP_NAME}" && /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0.172/bin/java -jar sikulix.jar -r executable.sikuli
```

Make script.sh executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Run script:

```
./script.sh /home/local/Applications/App/launch_app
```